# Why is Infinity / Infinity not 1?

Tags: javascript, math, infinity

If

```
Infinity === Infinity
>> true
```

and

```
typeOf Infinity
>> "number"
```

then why is

```
Infinity / Infinity
>>NaN
```

and not 1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beware any assumptions you make about the arithmetic behaviour of infinity.

If ∞/∞ = 1, then 1×∞ = ∞. By extension, since 2×∞ = ∞, it must also be the case that ∞/∞ = 2.

Since it has come up in discussion against another answer, I'd like to point out that the equation 2×∞ = ∞ does not imply that there are multiple infinities. All countably infinite sets have the same cardinality. I.e., the set of integers has the same cardinality as the set of odd numbers, even though the second set is missing half the elements from the first set. (OTOH, there are other *kinds* of "infinity", such as the cardinality of the set of reals, but doubling the countable infinity doesn't produce one of these. Nor does squaring it, for that matter.)

Answer (score 5):

Because the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.5.2) says so:

> Division of an infinity by an infinity results in **NaN**.

I'm not a mathematician, <del>but even from that point of view, having `1` as result it does not make sense. Infinities can be different and only because they are equal in JavaScript does not justify treating them as equal in all other cases (or letting the division return `1` for that matter).</del> (*edit:* as I said, I'm not a mathematician ;)).

Comment: But why is this in the specs?

Comment: Because Infinity and Infinity sometimes isn't the same. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel for example.

Comment: Ok, but then the question I should have been asking is, why does Infinity === Infinity return true

Comment: @Hierow `Infinity` would be useless if it would return false. Consider `var x = Infinity; if( x == Infinity ) ...`

Comment: There aren't different infinities. The point of Hilbert's hotel is to show that all countably infinite sets have the same cardinality, even if some seem larger than others. It is perfectly correct to assert that ∞ = ∞.

Comment: @Hierow: The specification says so because you can prove mathematically that infinity divided by infinity is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's recognizable from Calculus one! It's a indeterminate form!

Comment: Calculus also says that 1 / 0 is infinite instead of e.g. `DivideByZeroException`, but tell that to my compiler.

Comment: @Jon: 1/0 is undefined, but `lim(x->0) 1/x = Inf`. If you are using "standard" mathematics, that is.

Answer (score 1):

The result is mathematically undefined. It has nothing to do with javascript. See the [following explanation](http://www.philforhumanity.com/Infinity_Divided_by_Infinity.html).

Comment: The result that a Javascript compiler produces (which is what the OP is interested in) has *everything* to do with Javascript. The fact that it follows what math says is a bonus.

Comment: Well of course, but that design has nothing to do with the language itself. The language implements a mathimatical notion, which is why the answer to the question is mathematical and doesn't have anything to do with a programming language.

Comment: Agreed. But as I see it, the answer to *this question* is "because the spec says X". The answer to *"why does the spec say X and not Y"* is mathematical, as you say.